# Method should have no parameters

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

i have a simple unit test code in my android app that when implement it return error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Method constructorShouldSetTotal should have no parameters
```

and this is my code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class UserListClassParametrizedTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTotal() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {20},
                {50}
        });
    }
    @Test
    public void constructorShouldSetTotal(int total) {
        UserList userList = new UserList(total);
        assertEquals(total, userList.getTotal());
    }
}
```

as i searched some answers was using junitparams that i couldn't import it.
please guide me for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

my problem solved by removing input variable in test method and set it in constructor.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class UserListClassParametrizedTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTotal() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
                {80},
                {30}
        });
    }

    private int total;

    public UserListClassParametrizedTest(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    @Test
    public void constructorShouldSetTotal() {
        UserList userList = new UserList(total);
        assertEquals(total, userList.getTotal());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using JUnit please fix the order of the dependencies in your pom.xml ;)

Comment: do you have any comment for solving my problem?

Comment: If your' using JMockit then the dependency for it has to come first. If you're using Grails I'm not much expert in it.... It's hard to help you if we can see only few linex of code.